# Slow listView Sorting speed

Tags: .net, winforms, sorting, listview, c++-cli

### Description

I'm writing application what use `listView`. `listView` that I use is a simple list view, only I switch on `doubleBufer` by inheriting `listView` and in constructor I have write:

```
this->DoubleBuffer = true;
```

So I have some columns in my `listView` and when I click column I need to sort column items. Everything goes okay when I have 500 items, but when items count in `listView` become more then 50.000 and I press column in order to sort items in it, my list froze for 1 minute and application stop response. Below I present code of sorting.

### Sorting Code

```
ref class DomainSorter : public System::Collections::IComparer {
        public:
            virtual int Compare( System::Object^ x, System::Object^ y) {
                System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ lvi1 = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^>(o1);
                System::String^ str1 = lvi1->SubItems[COLUMN_DOMAIN]->Text;
                System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^ lvi2 = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::ListViewItem^>(o2);
                System::String^ str2 = lvi2->SubItems[COLUMN_DOMAIN]->Text;

                int result = 0;

                if( lvi1->ListView->Sorting == System::Windows::Forms::SortOrder::Ascending)
                     result = System::String::Compare( str1, str2 );
                else result = System::String::Compare( str2, str1 );

                return result;
            }

        };

void OnColumnClick( )
{
    listViewDomainsInfo->BeginUpdate( );
    listViewDomainsInfo->ListViewItemSorter = gcnew DomainSorter( );
    if (listViewDomainsInfo->Sorting == SortOrder::Ascending)
    listViewDomainsInfo->Sorting = SortOrder::Descending;
    else listViewDomainsInfo->Sorting = SortOrder::Ascending;
    listViewDomainsInfo->EndUpdate( ); 
}
```

### Question

How I can increase speed of `listView` sorting. (I knew that I can use virtual list but I didn't want) can you help me to make this code works faster ?

Comment: You're sorting **50,000 items**. There's no magic trick that's going to make that go any faster. You already know the solution--use virtual mode. This kind of situation is exactly what it's designed for. But you don't want to use that, so don't expect any miracles even if there are minor tweaks one could make to your sorting code.

Comment: Thanks a lot I just want to know if there another way to do that ! Now I know that there aren't !! How you think must I delete this question or no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the faster sorting you should not to use integrated sorting behavior.
For example:

1. Rewrite your sorting provider to work with `ListViewItem` instead `Object`
2. Sort items by yourself
3. Then call `listViewDomainsInfo->Items->Clear()` and `listViewDomainsInfo->Items->AddrRange()`

That's should work faster. Also note that you should restore visible items range manually in this case.

Comment: Why should working with `ListVIewItem` instead of `Object` be faster? They're both reference types; there's no boxing involved here. And he's already suspending updates with `BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate`, so it's unlikely that clearing and adding the items with `AddRange` will be any faster than what he's already done.

Comment: I has same problem in one of my project (file manager). I've solved the problem this way. Now sorting ~20000 takes less than 1 second (note that my sorting more complex). So I can guarantee that Clear() + AddRange() much faster than integrated ListView behavior.
And working directly with ListViewItem always faster than casting Object to ListViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do to avoid the unresponsive UI is to sort the items list on another thread (decoupled from the `ListView`) and when done call `ListView.Items.Clear` and `ListView.Items.AddRange` to add the sorted items to the `ListView`. Not sure if the infrastructural overhead of thread management and synchronization are worth the effort.